# Cannot locate 'id' value in database table when selecting column checked in UI (checkbox)

Tags: gridview, checkbox

Please help. This is for a UI I have worked on for about 6 weeks for my company's Client Services team that is itching to use it.

As in the title, I am trying to select an 'ID' value associated with a row that contains a checkbox. If that checkbox is 'checked' I want a select statement to run and grab the 'ID' value from that row.

```
protected void UpdateSelectedRecords()
{
  string strPerSignStart = "%";
  string strPerSignEnd = "%";
  string strDbSearch = strPerSignStart + ddlDatabasesUpdateTCID.Text +       strPerSignEnd;
  object NewTCID = txtTargetCID.Text;

  DateTime curtstmp = DateTime.Now;

  foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows) 
  {
    if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
       chkBox = (row.Cells[0].Controls[0] as CheckBox);

       if (chkBox != null && Convert.ToBoolean(chkBox.Checked) == true)
       {
         OdbcConnection Postgreconnect2 = new OdbcConnection("Driver=   {PostgreSQL   Unicode};Server=localhost;Port=5433;Database=postgres;Uid=xxx;Pwd=xxx");

         Postgreconnect2.Open();

         OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("SELECT id FROM conceptidmapping WHERE database ILIKE " + "?" + " AND " + (chkBox.Checked == true) + " ORDER BY id ASC", Postgreconnect2);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@database", strDbSearch);
         cmd.Parameters["@database"].Value = Convert.ToString(strDbSearch);
         cmd.Connection = Postgreconnect2;
         string idVal = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();


         OdbcCommand cmd1 = new OdbcCommand("UPDATE conceptidmapping SET selected = true WHERE database ILIKE " + "?" + " AND id = " + idVal, Postgreconnect2);
         cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@database", strDbSearch);
         cmd1.Parameters["@database"].Value = Convert.ToString(strDbSearch);
         cmd1.Connection = Postgreconnect2;
         cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: My apologies for not providing much info on this initially. What is happening is when the program enters the 'For' loop, it is navigating row by row through a Gridview (top to bottom). When it sees that Check Box is checked, it enters the second IF statement (with ODBC Commands). The first ODBC command attempts to locate the 'ID' value for that row. Once it has that 'ID' value, it then will use that in the second ODBC command to update the 'selected' column from 'false' to 'true'.

Comment: What is happening is it does grab an 'ID' value from the correct database but its never the one that I select the checkbox for. Does anyone see any simple flaws that I have in this approach? I am doing it all in the 'code-behind' file too (C#) because the first step in the process is to select a 'database' value from a drop-down list. I may be wrong but think it would tough to use that approach in a command populated in the markup. Any suggestions are very welcome!!

Answer (score 0):

GridViews are really good at displaying and managing data.  You state that you have *"an 'ID' value associated with a row"*.  But you don't, you actually make a DB call to retrieve the ID later

To me this screams "DataKey". Personally I would find a way to make the ID you need part of the dataset that populates the GridView, and then add the ID as a GridView DataKey.  This is how you associate an ID to a GridViewRow.  This allows you to eliminate the Select DB call in `UpdateSelectedRecords()`

However, sometime you don't have that option so here is your code, modified with both solutions and commented with some things for your consideration.

```
protected void UpdateSelectedRecords()
{
  ////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Since these are all local to the function
  //
  string strPerSignStart = "%";
  string strPerSignEnd = "%";
  string strDbSearch = strPerSignStart + ddlDatabasesUpdateTCID.Text + strPerSignEnd;
  //
  //////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Consider :
  string strDbSearch = String.Format("%{0}%", ddlDatabasesUpdateTCID.Text);


  //////////////////////////////////////////////
  // FYI These are never used
  //
  object NewTCID = txtTargetCID.Text;
  DateTime curtstmp = DateTime.Now;

  //////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Instantiate and open a connection once
  // also consider using the using() statement
  // it make managing connections much easier
  //
  using( OdbcConnection Postgreconnect2 = new OdbcConnection("Driver=   {PostgreSQL   Unicode};Server=localhost;Port=5433;Database=postgres;Uid=xxx;Pwd=xxx"));
  {
    Postgreconnect2.Open();

    // Instantiate commands once
    OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("", Postgreconnect2);
    OdbcCommand cmd1 = new OdbcCommand("", Postgreconnect2);

    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows) 
    {
      if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
      {
        chkBox = (row.Cells[0].Controls[0] as CheckBox);

        //////////////////////////////////
        // chkBox.Checked *is* a boolean value, no need to convert to Bool 
        //
        if (chkBox != null && chkBox.Checked)
        {
          //////////////////////////////////
          // Since strDbSearch doesn't change 
          // just make it part of the select string you are building
          // This eliminates the need for parameter passing
          // 
          // Also, check the string you are building
          // It doesn't look like it builds a proper SELECT statement
          // You're missing a field after "AND"
          cmd.CommandText = 
              "SELECT id FROM conceptidmapping "
              "WHERE database ILIKE " + strDbSearch + " AND " +
              (chkBox.Checked == true) + " ORDER BY id ASC";

          //////////////////////////////////
          // No parameters necessary, but...
          // This already assigns the value to the parameter
          //
          //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@database", strDbSearch);
          //
          // So there is no need to do it again here
          //
          //cmd.Parameters["@database"].Value = Convert.ToString(strDbSearch);


          string idVal = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

          ///////////////////////////////////
          // IF YOU ARE ABLE TO MAKE THE ID A DATAKEY
          // Then the entire cmd for the select call above 
          // can be removed in favor of this:
          //
          string idVal = Gridview1.DataKeys(row.RowIndex).Values("id")

          cmd1.CommandText = "UPDATE conceptidmapping SET selected = true WHERE database ILIKE " + strDBSearch + " AND id = "  + idVal ;

          cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Same Code above without comments and done with a datakey

```
protected void UpdateSelectedRecords()
{
  string strDbSearch = String.Format("%{0}%", ddlDatabasesUpdateTCID.Text);

  using( OdbcConnection Postgreconnect2 = new OdbcConnection("Driver=   {PostgreSQL   Unicode};Server=localhost;Port=5433;Database=postgres;Uid=xxx;Pwd=xxx"));
  {
    Postgreconnect2.Open();
    OdbcCommand cmd1 = new OdbcCommand("", Postgreconnect2);

    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows) 
    {
      if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
      {
        chkBox = (row.Cells[0].Controls[0] as CheckBox);
        if (chkBox != null && chkBox.Checked)
        {
          string idVal = Gridview1.DataKeys(row.RowIndex).Values("id");

          cmd1.CommandText = String.Format("UPDATE conceptidmapping SET selected = true WHERE database ILIKE {0} AND id = {1}", strDbSearch, idVal) ;
          cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```